# android textview right of a multiline textview

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]i am suppose to place a `TextView` right of a multiline `TextView`.

please check the code below .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rltest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rlanswer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grdiviewspacing"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grdiviewspacing"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblanswer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/strbookmarkmessage"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/listviewlocationsize"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnyesiwillcollectitby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblanswer2"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/stryesiwillcollectitby"
        android:textColor="@color/linkcolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/listviewlocationsize" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i have tried the problem with the above code is its not showing the second `TextView`. where us if i try `layout_below` - its showing the second text view. can anyone please assists me..
i want something like this - blue textview text to read textview.

Comment: @Segi "never use relativelayout..." Are you serious? Why???

Comment: yes, because its not good for design purpose for all devices..

Comment: @Segi that's a terrible advice.

Comment: RelativeLayouts are much more powerful than LinearLayouts, and with them you don't have to create deep hierarchies in the XML. Deep hierarchies done with LinearLayouts are longer to load than the wide ones created with RelativeLayouts.

Comment: With all of this said about `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, in this situation a `LinearLayout` may work better but its hard to say without seeing the entire `layout`. But, in general, `RelativeLayout` is better for performance and can provide more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and give `layout_weight=1` to both the `TextView` you will get result whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using a `RelativeLayout`, you will have to set the width in dip (instead of wrap_content) for the `TextView` "lblanswer2", otherwise it will always take the whole place if your text is long.

If using a `RelativeLayout` is not a necessity, you can follow pratik's answer and implement a `LinearLayout`, this way your 2 `TextViews` will share the width equally.